# How could I shuffle python infinite generator

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

I have an object which I make it to be an generator:

```
class obj(object):
     def __init__():
         pass
     def __iter__():
         a = list(range(10))
         shuffle(a)
         for i in range(len(a)):
             yield a[i]
     .....
```

It can be seen that there is a shuffle operation when the generator is created. When I use `itertools.cycle`, this generator can works infinitely, but no shuffle operator will be done except the first time. How could I create an infinite generator behaves like `itertools.cycle` but can still implement shuffle each cycle ?

Comment: Implement `def __next__`. What are you shuffling? And what do you *return* in `__iter__`?

Comment: @trincot Sorry, I might have misunderstood generator with iterator. I modified the question.

Comment: @trincot Sorry, I might have misunderstood generator with iterator. I modified the question.

Comment: Why would you want to shuffle more than once? Is it because you want to have a probability to return the same list value more than once, and some others never? As you want to define a *generator* (yield), don't name it `__iter__`, but give it a normal name. `__iter__` is for making your class instances iterable.

Comment: @trincot Not exactly, I am actually training a neural network, it requires the training samples to be fed in random order each cycle.

Comment: Yes, but surely you want to produce all the shuffled values, and only *after* having provided the *complete* list, shuffle it again. It makes really no sense in shuffling it before *every* individual pick of a value from the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: don't call your generator `__iter__` as that is reserved for making your object instances iterable (without a call to a specific method).

For generating an infinite list of values, you would not really need to shuffle. Instead just pick a random value from the list each time. Add logic if you want to prevent the same value to be picked too soon after the previous same pick, although the more you control that, the less random it becomes.

```
import random

class obj(object):
     def __init__(self):
         pass
     def items(self):  # Generator
         a = list(range(10))
         while True:
             yield random.choice(a)
```

If your list `a` really is just a sequence from 0 to 9 (included), then do:

```
     def items(self):  # Generator
         while True:
             yield random.randint(0, 10)
```

If you really want all list values to have been produced before restarting, then please be aware that the last pick of the first batch might be the same as the first pick from the second batch. Anyway, that would look like this:

```
     def items(self):  # Generator
         a = list(range(10))
         while True:
             shuffle(a)
             yield from a
```

Comment: I think the last solution is probably what the asker meant by "implement shuffle each cycle"

Comment: Trivia: The third solution here is the shuffle used in Tetris. It's less random than purely random.choice(), as it allows you to do card counting so that your chances of guessing the next tile are better than chance, but has the benefit that it guarantees you'll never go too long without seeing any particular pieces.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle

class my_generator():
    n = 10
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        a = list(range(self.n))
        shuffle(a)
        for i in range(len(a)):
            yield a[i]

    def get(self):
        my_list = []
        for i in range(self.n):
            my_list.append(self.__iter__().__next__())

        return my_list


obj =my_generator()
my_list = obj.get()
print(my_list)
```